# How can add an element to an array?

Tags: java

I wrote this code with a String array:

```
public static String[] prgmNameList = {"bbbbb", "aaaaa"};
```

My question is now, how can I add a new item to that array like this:

```
prgmNameList.add("cccc");
```

Comment: I would suggest looking at [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). You should start with the block "Trails covernig the Basics". Both arrays and the `Collection` interface get explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prgmNameList` is an array. The size of an array object cannot be changed once it has been created. If you want a variable size container, use collections. For example, use an `ArrayList` :

```
List<String> prgmNameList = new ArrayList<String>(3);
prgmNameList.add("bbbb");
```

That said, if you insist on using an array, you will need to copy your initial array into a new array for each new element that you want to add to the array which can be expensive. See [System#arrayCopy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) for more details. In fact, the `ArrayList` class internally uses an array that is expanded once it is full using `System.arrayCopy` so why reinvent the wheel? Just use an `ArrayList`

Answer (score 1):

On simpler terms, note these following points:

- Array size is always fixed.(In your example you fixed the array size to 2 by adding 2 elements)
- Arrays operate based on index starting from '0' zero, like - `prgmNameList[0]` will return 1st element added in the array
- Array size cannot be changed at any point of time. ***If you need size to be variable, choose one of `List` implementations***
- ArrayList is the best option for your need that can define itself as an 'Array that can shrink or grow'

Sample code:

```
public static List<String> prgmNameList= new ArrayList<String>();
prgmNameList.add("bbb");
prgmNameList.add("bbb");
prgmNameList.add("ccc");
prgmNameList.remove("bbb"); //Removes by object resolved by equals() method
prgmNameList.remove(2); //Removes by index
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ArrayList like that

```
 ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();


  // add elements to the array list
  al.add("C");
  al.add("A");
  al.add("E");
  al.add("B");
```

if you want to use array as you did you have to know the number of elements that you want to add

String[] myList = new String[10];

and then

```
myList[4]="AA"
```

--
this is not possible to add to myList.
I explain you how ArrayList works and then you will understand.

ArrayList is an class that contains Array from objects. every time you add it check if it have place to store the data in the array if not it creates new array bigger and store the data.

So ArrayList this is the solution (or any other list)
if you want to add to myList you will have to implement arratList..

Comment: but i want to add my List

Answer (score 0):

You have created an Array which can not grow as it's fixed in size.
You need to create a list in order to add new elements as shown below.

```
List<String> prgmNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
prgmNameList.add("aaaa");
prgmNameList.add("bbbb");
prgmNameList.add("cccc");
```

Answer (score -1):

The method you are looking for is defined for a [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add-E-), but you are using an array with an array initializer.

I suggest switching to the `List`:

```
public static List<String> prgmNameList= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("bbbbb","aaaaa"))
```

Then you can call `add` on it because now it is a list.
Btw.: Try to prevent having mutable variables in `static` variables.

Comment: Yeah, you are right - I miss my compiler - thanks for jumping in ;)

Comment: Why would one want to avoid mutable static variables in particular?

Comment: Because of encapsulation, they are visible (and changeable) globally in your VM. Doesn't matter for a programming beginner though, because the program most likely will not reach a critical size - but I thought it might be worth trying to adapt to good practices early on ;)